# Drawing a hero and moving it

Tags: java, android, bitmap

What is the best way drawing a hero and moving it? I just need the best code for doing that. Before writing this i found a way, but when i made the surface holder transparent, i realised that the code is drawing new bitmap in the front of the old one every milisecond. That way looks kind of laggy to me, but maymie i'm not right. Please help me. Actualy i'm kind of confused...

Anyway, here's the code that i think is laggy:
MainThread.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.workspace.pockethero;


import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;


/**
 * @author impaler
 *
 * The Main thread which contains the game loop. The thread must have access to 
 * the surface view and holder to trigger events every game tick.
 */
public class MainThread extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

    // Surface holder that can access the physical surface
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    // The actual view that handles inputs
    // and draws to the surface
    private MainGamePanel gamePanel;

    // flag to hold game state 
    private boolean running;
    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
            // in the surface
            try {
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // update game state
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    // render state to the screen
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
                // an inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }   // end finally
        }
    }

}
```

MainGamePanel.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.workspace.pockethero;

import com.workspace.pockethero.model.Droid;
import com.workspace.pockethero.buttons.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;


/**
 * @author impaler
 * This is the main surface that handles the ontouch events and draws
 * the image to the screen.
 */
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

    private MainThread thread;
    public Droid droid;
    public Butt butt;
    public Butt1 butt1;
    public Butt2 butt2;
    public Butt3 butt3;
    public Buttz buttz;
    public Buttz1 buttz1;
    public Buttz2 buttz2;
    public Buttz3 buttz3;
    public Buttx buttx;
    public Build build;
    public int decentreX;
    public int decentreY;
    public int debottomA;
    public boolean moved;
    public boolean moved1;
    public boolean moved2;
    public boolean moved3;
    public boolean moved4;
    public boolean moved5;
    public boolean moved6;
    public boolean moved7;
    private Drawable myImage;
    public boolean mapPainted;

    public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // create droid and load bitmap
        decentreX = PocketHero.centreX;
        decentreY = PocketHero.centreY;
        debottomA = PocketHero.bottomA;


        droid = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herod), decentreX, decentreY);
        butt = new Butt(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button), 110, debottomA - 70);
        butt1 = new Butt1(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button1), 70, debottomA - 110);
        butt2 = new Butt2(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button2), 30, debottomA - 70);
        butt3 = new Butt3(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button3), 70, debottomA - 30);
        buttz = new Buttz(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.zbutton), 110, debottomA - 110);
        buttz1 = new Buttz1(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.zbutton1), 30, debottomA - 110);
        buttz2 = new Buttz2(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.zbutton2), 30, debottomA - 30);
        buttz3 = new Buttz3(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.zbutton3), 110, debottomA - 30);
        buttx = new Buttx(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.xbutton), 70, debottomA - 70);
        build = new Build(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.building), 500, 200);
        // create the game loop thread

        //300 indicates start position of bitmapfield on screen


        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View V, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // delegating event handling to the droid
                    handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    // the gestures
                } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // touch was released
                    if (droid.touched) {
                        droid.setTouched(false);
                    }
                    if (droid.touched1) {
                        droid.setTouched1(false);
                    }
                    if (droid.touched2) {
                        droid.setTouched2(false);
                    }
                    if (droid.touched3) {
                        droid.setTouched3(false);
                    }

                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // at this point the surface is created and
        // we can safely start the game loop
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
        // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
        // this is a clean shutdown
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
    }


    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        droid.draw(canvas);
        butt.draw(canvas);
        butt1.draw(canvas);
        butt2.draw(canvas);
        butt3.draw(canvas);
        buttz.draw(canvas);
        buttz1.draw(canvas);
        buttz2.draw(canvas);
        buttz3.draw(canvas);
        buttx.draw(canvas);
    }
    /**
     * This is the game update method. It iterates through all the objects
     * and calls their update method if they have one or calls specific
     * engine's update method.
     */
    public void update() {
        droid.update();
        }
    public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
          if (eventX >= (butt.x - butt.bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (butt.x + butt.bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
           if (eventY >= (buttz.y - buttz.bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (eventY <= (buttz3.y + buttz3.bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
            // droid touched
            droid.setTouched(true);
           } else {
               droid.setTouched(false);
           }
          } else {
               droid.setTouched(false);

           } 

              if (eventX >= (buttz1.x - buttz1.bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (buttz.x + buttz.bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
               if (eventY >= (butt1.y - butt1.bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (eventY <= (butt1.y + butt1.bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
                    // droid touched
                    droid.setTouched1(true);
                   } else {
                       droid.setTouched1(false);
                   }
                  }else {
                       droid.setTouched1(false);

                   }
              if (eventX >= (butt2.x - butt2.bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (butt2.x + butt2.bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
                   if (eventY >= (buttz1.y - buttz1.bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (eventY <= (buttz2.y + buttz2.bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
                        // droid touched
                        droid.setTouched2(true);
                       } else {
                           droid.setTouched2(false);
                       }
                      }else {
                           droid.setTouched2(false);

                       }
              if (eventX >= (buttz2.x - buttz2.bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (buttz3.x + buttz3.bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
                   if (eventY >= (butt3.y - butt3.bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (eventY <= (butt3.y + butt3.bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
                        // droid touched
                        droid.setTouched3(true);
                       } else {
                           droid.setTouched3(false);
                       }
                      }else {
                           droid.setTouched3(false);

                       }


              if (droid.touched & !droid.touched1 & !droid.touched3) {
                  if (!moved) {
                  droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.heror);
                  moved = true;
                  }
                }else {
                    moved = false;
                }if (droid.touched1 & !droid.touched & !droid.touched2){
                     if (!moved1) {
                    droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herou);
                     moved1 = true;
                     }
                }else {
                    moved1 = false;
                } if (droid.touched2 & !droid.touched1 & !droid.touched3){
                     if (!moved2) {
                         droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herol);
                    moved2 = true;
                 }
            }else {
                moved2 = false;
            } if (droid.touched3 & !droid.touched2 & !droid.touched){
                if (!moved7) {
                    droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herod);
                    moved7 = true;
             }
        }else {
            moved7 = false;
        } if (droid.touched & droid.touched1){
                    if (!moved3) {
                        droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herour);
                    moved3 = true;
                 }
            }else {
                moved3 = false;
            } if (droid.touched1 & droid.touched2){
                if (!moved4) {
                    droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.heroul);
                    moved4 = true;
             }
        }else {
            moved4 = false;
        } if (droid.touched2 & droid.touched3){
            if (!moved5) {
                droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herodl);
                    moved5 = true;
         }
    }else {
        moved5 = false;
    } if (droid.touched3 & droid.touched){
        if (!moved6) {
            droid.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.herodr);
                    moved6 = true;
     }
}else {
    moved6 = false;
}



         }
}
```

and the Droid.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.workspace.pockethero.model;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

/**
 * This is a test droid that is dragged, dropped, moved, smashed against
 * the wall and done other terrible things with.
 * Wait till it gets a weapon!
 * 
 * @author impaler
 *
 */
public class Droid {

    public Bitmap bitmap;   // the actual bitmap
    public int x;           // the X coordinate
    public int y;           // the Y coordinate
    public boolean touched; // if droid is touched/picked up
    public boolean touched1;    // if droid is touched/picked up
    public boolean touched2;    // if droid is touched/picked up
    public boolean touched3;    // if droid is touched/picked up

    public Droid(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }



    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), y - (bitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
    }

    /**
     * Method which updates the droid's internal state every tick
     */

    public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
        this.touched = touched;
    }

public boolean isTouched() {
    return touched;
}
public void setTouched1(boolean touched) {
    this.touched1 = touched;
}

public boolean isTouched1() {
return touched1;
}
public void setTouched2(boolean touched) {
    this.touched2 = touched;
}

public boolean isTouched2() {
return touched2;
}

public void setTouched3(boolean touched) {
    this.touched3 = touched;
}

public boolean isTouched3() {
return touched3;
}

    public void update() {
        if (touched & !touched1 & !touched3) {
            x += 1;
        }else if (touched1 & !touched & !touched2){
            y -= 1;

        }else if (touched2 & !touched1 & !touched3){
            x -= 1;
        }else if (touched3 & !touched2 & !touched){
            y += 1;
        }else if (touched & touched1){
            x += 1;
            y -= 1;
        }else if (touched1 & touched2){
            x -= 1;
            y -= 1;
        }else if (touched2 & touched3){
            x -= 1;
            y += 1;
        }else if (touched3 & touched){
            x += 1;
            y += 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the {@link MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN} event. If the event happens on the 
     * bitmap surface then the touched state is set to <code>true</code> otherwise to <code>false</code>
     * @param eventX - the event's X coordinate
     * @param eventY - the event's Y coordinate
     */
}
```

there are also other classes created for each button, but i didnt pasted them here, because the are practicly the same as droid.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-drawing the whole frame each loop is the correct way to draw/move sprites and perform anything with canvas.

The buffer is cleared each frame and you need to re-draw the background and all objects at their specified position.

In your code render() and update() will not be called more frequently than approximately every 16milliseconds~ (60 frames per second), so all you have to think about is drawing the onscreen scene.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'laggy', maybe you have a performance issue related to the size of your Bitmaps or phone performance, but I hope this is close to what you were looking for.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But there is another problem. I added a script to the render(Canvas, canvas) method int the Main game panel class, which creates a map, but the hero started walking very slowly. That's what i call laggy. Do you need the script?

Comment: If your game is running slowly due to your rendering code, this can be caused by any number of things. You should make sure not to create any Paints or Drawables in your rendering code and set up as much as you can before rendering

You might find reading up on Android DDMS Method Profiling useful, it can show you what methods in your render code are taking up most CPU time an you could likely go from here to pinpoint the problem